# Is there any avatar supposed to be born between the death of Krishna and the birth of Kalki?

Tags: krishna, gods, avatars, goddess, kali-yuga

I am curious if an avatar between the death of Krishna and the birth of Kalki is supposed to be born no matter of what god we are talking, no matter if its an incarnation of Shiva, Brahma, Vishnu, Durga, Surya, Agni etc..

Comment: Adi Shankara is believed to be incarnation of Shiva!

Comment: Golden boy is suppose to incarnate.

Answer (score 7):

[SB 1.3.24](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3)

> Then, in the beginning of Kali-yuga, the Lord will appear as Lord Buddha...

So Buddha is mentioned after Krishna and before Kalki incarnation.